# Flux of two open surfaces sharing the same boundary in a solenoidal field

Tags: vector-fields, surface-integrals

I am studying for exam and I come across a dilemma.

Assume that:

$$
\vec{F}=\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{A}
$$

This implies that we are in a solenoidal or divergence-less vector field.

It is given that
$\oint{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}}=0$. Prove that $\int{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}}$ is independent of surface, for any given boundary line.

My attempt to solve this is to cut a closed surface $S$ into any two open surfaces, $S_1$ and $S_2$, as long as they are different from each other but shares a common boundary.

$$
\oint_S{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}}=0
$$

$$
\int_{S_1}{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}} + \int_{S_2}{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}}=0
$$

$$
\int_{S_1}{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}} = -\int_{S_2}{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}}
$$

Here comes the dilemma, the two above must be equal to prove that $\int{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}}$ is independent of surface, for any given boundary line. For some reason, the two has opposite sign.

The only reason I can think to solve this is for the $d\vec{s}$ of two integrals to have opposite signs. This will make the integrals equal. But this does not really make sense to me. At least, I can't imagine why this is the case.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) ? You should distinguish the surface from its (closed) boundary and notice that on the surface you integrate $F$ while on the boundary you integrate $A$.

Comment: HI @KurtG.! Correct me if I am wrong, does applying Stokes' theorem mean that $\int_{S_1}{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}}$ and $\int_{S_2}{\vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s}}$ are equal but they traverse in different directions? Or I have written something wrong in my solution and arrived at a wrong conclusion?

Comment: I assume now that all your integrals are surface integrals. Note that $d\vec{s}$ is the outward normal vector of the closed surface $S$. Hence, the "hemispheres" $S_1$ and $S_2$ have opposite orientations. This is compatible with the minus sign you found. When you choose the normal vector for $S_2$ in opposite direction the minus sign disappears and you can say that the two surface integrals are equal and share the same boundary.

Comment: Hi! I solved it already! I also proved the opposite orientations using the Stokes' Theorem. I admit that I forgot to connect this theorem to this question. I am very thankful for you help! This is my first time posting in this site, so thank you for a very warm welcome!

Comment: Stokes' theorem applies and relates $\int_{\partial S_1}A\cdot d\vec{r}$ with $\int_{\partial S_2}A\cdot d\vec{r}$ and with the surface integrals. However, we did not really need it. Do you know why $\int_SF\cdot d\vec{s}$ was zero in the first place ? Hint: Green's theorem and divergence free .

Comment: I used Stokes' theorem to prove that the surfaces has opposite orientations. It seems that there is no need to do it because their opposite orientation, based on your logic, is obvious. I still included it in my notes for future purposes though. As for your question, kinda! I have yet to fully understand but I kind of get what to do. I will try to answer it in my notes!!!